# react-leaflet when i try to add circles my map is white

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

Hello I try to add circles to my react-leaflet map and when I do that my map is white and I see only the circles I hope someone can help me to solve this problem I tried a lot of things but nothing worked here is the code =>

````
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Tooltip, Popup, Circle } from 'react-leaflet';
import './map.scss';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';


class MapComp extends React.Component {
    state = {
        lat: 55.702868,
        lng: 37.530865,
        zoom: 3
    };

    render() {
        var center = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];

        return (
            <Map zoom={this.state.zoom} center={center}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />

                <Circle key='1' center={[this.state.lat, this.state.lng]} radius={20} />);
            </Map>
        );
    }
}

export default MapComp```
````

Comment: Working for me (cleaned up two typos: `attribution='&amp;copy` should read `attribution='&copy;` and changed `radius={20} />);` to `radius={20} />`) Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/circle-layer-in-react-leaflet-zjnti).

Comment: still don't work i changed to code to this `return (
            <Map zoom={this.state.zoom} center={center}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Circle key='1' center={[this.state.lat, this.state.lng]} radius={20} />
            </Map>
        );`

Comment: idk what should fix this

Comment: possibly somewhere else in your code? Also, you're importing `/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css` twice.

Comment: I also fixed this but still don't work

Comment: i saw a lot of videos with this code and that worked here is the css for the map `@import url("~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css");

body,
#root,
.leaflet-container {
  height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
`

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? failure to load TileLayer url?

Comment: no, I don't idk whats happening

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working snippet.

```js
const { Map, TileLayer, Circle } = window.ReactLeaflet

class MapComp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    lat: 55.702868,
    lng: 37.530865,
    zoom: 10
  };

  render() {
    var center = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];

    return (
      <Map zoom={this.state.zoom} center={center}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Circle key="1" center={center} radius={2000} />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MapComp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.leaflet-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
  crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
  crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-leaflet/2.8.0/react-leaflet.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: if you can look closer this is also what I have but don't work

Comment: I can only guess it's somewhere else in your code, possibly conflict in `.map.scss`. I can't do more I'm afraid.

Comment: in map.scss i only have `@import url("~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css");

.leaflet-container {
  height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
`

Comment: and if I add a circle I only see the circle and map and the map will be white